# http.get() Gets Deserialized JSON but Returns HTTP Response?

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-service, angular-promise

In my Angular app I have a `baseController.js` class and a class `exampleController.js` which can access the functions defined in `baseController` through injecting its own scope into baseController. This allows for shared functionality between all controllers.

This is working except for in the case where I try to make a call to the `getDataFromUrl()` function from `exampleController`. While debugging I can see that `getDataFromUrl()` gets called, and it enters the `.success()` function of the `$http.get()` call. At that point I can see that `data` is a deserialized JSON object (in this case, it's an array of objects) BUT when the code finally comes back to `exampleController`'s `initArray()` function the `data` that it ultimately recieves is no longer a deserialized object but has turned into the raw HTTP response data.

**baseController.js:**

```
// Data retrieval function for all derived controllers
$scope.getDataFromUrl = function (url) {
    return $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
        return data;
    })
    .error(function () {
        return null;
    });
};
```

**exampleController.js:**

```
appModule.controller('exampleController', [
        '$scope', '$controller', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$timeout',
        function ($scope, $controller, $http, $window, $location, $timeout) {
            var base = $controller('baseController', { $scope: $scope });

            // Initiate an array of data
            var initArray = function (data) {
                $scope.sortedArray = sortDataByDate(data);
            };

            // Calling function in scope defined by base controller class
            $scope.getDataFromUrl('resources/data').then(function (data) {
                initArray(data);
            });
}]);
```

Why is `data` coming back to `exampleController` as an HTTP response? I want it to stay as deserialized JSON!

Comment: Curious. Why is your `getDataFromUrl()` function tied to the `$scope`?

Comment: @Brett the scope is how the base controller and derived controller share data or functionality in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I was getting raw response data because `.then()` doesn't fire as a result of `.success()` so the data that gets to the child controller was never deserialized to begin with. Here is the correct code:

**baseController.js:**

```
// Data retrieval function for all derived controllers
$scope.getDataFromUrl = function (url, successFunction) {
    $http.get(url)
    .success(function (data) {
        successFunction(data);
    })
    .error(function () {
        return null; // Or whatever you want to return
    });
};
```

**exampleController.js:**

```
appModule.controller('exampleController', [
        '$scope', '$controller', '$http', '$window', '$location', '$timeout',
        function ($scope, $controller, $http, $window, $location, $timeout) {
            var base = $controller('baseController', { $scope: $scope });

            // Initiate an array of data
            var initArray = function (data) {
                $scope.sortedArray = sortDataByDate(data);
            };

            // Calling function in scope defined by base controller class
            $scope.getDataFromUrl('resources/data', function (data) {
                initArray(data);
            });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `success` and `error` callbacks should no belong in your `getDataFromUrl()` function. Besides, you can't return data to the caller like that from an asynchronous call. Instead the function should return a promise to the `$http` call and then handle the success from the caller. That's one way to do it.

```
$scope.getDataFromUrl = function (url) {
  // return a promise to the async action and handle `success` and `error` in the caller
  return $http.get(url);
};

// for example
$scope.getDataFromUrl('resources/data').then(function (data) {
  initArray(data);
});
// or
$scope.getDataFromUrl('resources/data').success(function (data) {
  initArray(data);
}).error(function() {
  alert('Server error');
});
```

Comment: Hmm but the reason we're using a base controller is to keep all of the error handling logic in one place so it doesn't have to be copy/pasted into every call to `getDataFromUrl`...